# reCAPTCHA 'challenge' does not show up in same div as v2 checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, modal-dialog, recaptcha

I am using a modal popup to contain my reCAPTCHA (grecaptcha.render method). I assumed that the 'challenge' box would also be placed in this same div because I do not see a separate parameter under the g-recaptcha tag attributes, grecaptcha.render parameters or JavaScript API (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param). Obviously, my assumption was wrong (see screenshot). I am not finding any references to this in my (many) searches. Am I missing something or is this just not possible (meaning the reCAPTCHA API does not support?). I would appreciate knowing how to get the 'challenge' to appear in the same div as the checkbox.

[image: Screenshot showing challenge window BEHIND modal div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge box is rendered into a separate fixed positioned `div` which has another `iframe` of its own. make sure that modal popup `z-index` is lower than the challenge box `div`.

Comment: Great input. I was toying with the z-index idea but could not find any info on the "fixed positioned div" you mention. Is this documented anywhere that you know of? I will look at Dev Tools to determine the current index.

Comment: My modal setup has several dimensions that will each need the z-index set because I do not have access to the Google iframe z-index property. I have tested in Dev Tools and it works so I will now integrate into my code and select your answer - with my thanks..